# Переменная $ не создается в документе php

Tags: php, переменные, php5

Использую функцию

```
$filename_out=$login.'.php'; 
$f_out=fopen($filename_out,"w+t") or die("Ошибка при создании файла");
fwrite($f_out,"<?php"); 
fwrite($f_out,"\n"."header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')?>");
fwrite($f_out,"\n"."<?php $connect_db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')");
fwrite($f_out,"\n"."include ('bd.php');");
```

и так далее. Создается новая страница( вроде все нормально), но знак переменной ("$") не копируется в новый документ. Просто ставится пробел. Подскажите что делать.

Comment: либо '$connect_db..', либо "\$connect_db..."

Comment: и никто не спросил, зачем создавать файл  несуществующей в языке функцией

Comment: Ипатьев@  Вы имеете ввиду функцию mysql_connect ?
Так она вроде существует.

Comment: @китайецИзКитая она существует в версии языка устаревшей более 4 лет назад.

Comment: @u_mulder так автор повесил метку что он работает на  php5,  значит для него эта функция актуальна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте файл connect.php
в котором разместите код

```
<?php 
$connect_db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')");
?>
```

а в вашем коде генерации вместо строки

```
fwrite($f_out,"\n"."<?php $connect_db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')");
```

поставьте строку

```
fwrite($f_out,"\n"."<?php include ('connect.php');");
```

Comment: То есть получается два файла. Один мой начальный, а второй со строчками "fwrite($f_out,"\n"."<?php include ('connect.php');");" . Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Пятую строчку из Вашего кода что выше замените на  fwrite($f_out,"\n"."<?php include ('connect.php');")      И создайте файл connect.php в котором содержится код   <?php 
$connect_db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')");
?>